# Better typed function to generate media queries

Tags: typescript, styled-components

I am following along with this post: https://medium.com/@samuelresua/easy-media-queries-in-styled-components-690b78f50053

I have created the following in Typescript, but have had to resort to typing to `any` more than I have to I'm sure:

```
const breakpoints: ObjectMap<number> = {
  small: 767,
  medium: 992,
  large: 1200,
  extraLarge: 1240
};

export const media = Object.keys(breakpoints).reduce((acc: { [key: string]: (...args: any) => any }, label) => {
  acc[label] = (...args) => css`
     @media (min-width: ${breakpoints[label]}px) {
        ${css(...args as [any])};
     }
  `;
  return acc;
}, {});
```

As a result, I have no help in my IDE when I'm writing styles in my media query blocks:

```
styled.button<Props>`
  background: red; /* this must be a valid style */
  ${({ theme }) => theme.media.large`
      background: blue;
      foo: bar; /* this isn't caught */
   `
```

Anyone know how I can improve my `media` function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`styled-components` lets you use objects for CSS properties as well as template strings, and objects are much better understood by the TypeScript compiler. Try this:

```
const breakpoints: ObjectMap<number> = {
  small: 767,
  medium: 992,
  large: 1200,
  extraLarge: 1240
};

export const media = (size: keyof typeof breakpoints, properties: CSSObject) => ({[`@media (min-width: ${breakpoints[size]})`]: properties});

const MyButton = styled.button<Props>(({ theme }) => ({
  background: red, // this must be a valid style
  ...theme.media('large', {
    background: blue // this is also validated :)
  })
}));
```

Answer (score 5):

I believe the isn’t a TypeScript issue but rather an IntelliSense plugin issue.

From the perspective of TypeScript, the content between the backticks is of type `TemplateStringsArray`. TypeScript isn’t aware of valid CSS properties as it sees an array of strings.

I believe the validation is done at the plugin level by [typescript-styled-plugin](https://github.com/Microsoft/typescript-styled-plugin).

See https://github.com/styled-components/vscode-styled-components/pull/41

I would submit a feature request or bug report [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/typescript-styled-plugin/issues).

Comment: I'd still like to improve my media query if possible... But thanks for the input!

Comment: Let’s wait and see if my assumption is wrong and others have a solution. In the meantime, I just noticed that CSS validation doesn’t appear to work for styles within [@media CSS at-rules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media) potentially confirming this limitation of the IntelliSense plugin.

Comment: I just submitted a bug report. https://github.com/microsoft/typescript-styled-plugin/issues/113

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you want to get rid of `any`.

Here's how you can do it:

```
import {
  css,
  CSSObject,
  SimpleInterpolation,
  FlattenSimpleInterpolation,
} from 'styled-components';

type ObjectMap<T> = {[key: string]: T};

const breakpoints: ObjectMap<number> = {
  small: 767,
  medium: 992,
  large: 1200,
  extraLarge: 1240,
};

export const media = Object.keys(breakpoints).reduce(
  (
    acc: {
      [key: string]: (
        first: TemplateStringsArray | CSSObject,
        ...interpolations: SimpleInterpolation[]
      ) => FlattenSimpleInterpolation;
      // ^^^ this is the first implementation of  `BaseThemedCssFunction`
    },
    label
  ) => {
    acc[label] = (...args) => css`
      @media (min-width: ${breakpoints[label]}px) {
        ${css(...args)};
      }
    `;
    return acc;
  },
  {}
);
```